# Julia: Loading an rds file using RData.jl takes up a huge amount of memory

Tags: r, julia, rdata

I'm loading an R rds file into Julia with

```
using RData
objs = load(rds, convert=true)
```

The original rds file is ~3GB. When I run the `load` function about, the memory spikes to ~40GB.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rds` files are actually compressed using gzip. Try unzipping your file and see how big it actually is (on Windows you could use 7-zip for that). The compression level for a dataframe easily could be around 80-90% so your numbers look fine.

Comment: @user3055163 by the way - why have you deleted your question about parallelization of `DataFrame`s it was a good question and it took me some time and effort to write the answer and now it is not visible by other Julia users.

Comment: The question was badly formulated. In hindsight I realise I was asking about multi-threading, not multi-processing.

Comment: 1. Still the multiprocessing answer was useful for the others. 2. If you need multi-threading just submit one more question or ask for clarification in the last one - I will be happy to provide code snippet for that too.